# What Christian denomination am I a part of?

Tags: denomination-survey, non-denominational

I have been brought up in a church group where our church history has never been taught and they refuse to call themselves anything other than Christian. This makes it very difficult for me to research how they started from a historical perspective.

If anyone has an idea of what it could be, I would be very thankful.

Here are some practices and beliefs unique (again, I say this with some uncertainty) to this group.

1. 7 Dispensations and frequent teaching of them.
2. Women in church should write their questions on slips of paper, then hand it to a man to read out loud for them.
3. High regard for the Darby Translation.
4. Saying “Lord’s Day” instead of Sunday.
5. Their own hymn book, called “Spiritual Songs.”

Some beliefs and practices that are broadly found in other denominations but might help in identifying this one are:

Believers cannot lose their salvation.
Believers baptism.
The Eucharist (or as they call it, Breaking of Bread) is only symbolic.
Women veiling during meetings and services.
No Ecclesiastical structure or even any titles of “pastor” and the like.
Belief in the doctrine of Predestination.

I hope somebody might be able to help me out.

Comment: If this were in the UK then I doubt very much that it is Open Brethren. I would suggest that it is Taylor Brethren or Exclusive Brethren. Due to the controversy in regard to the denial of the Eternal Sonship of the Lord Jesus Christ some Taylor Brethren choose to call themselves 'Plymouth Brethren', harking back to the origins of the movement, but maintaining their doctrine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Curious Danni that the denomination you describe sounds very much like a branch of the Brethren.  Dispensationalism, predestination, women not allowed to ask their own questions in church and to cover their heads, and referring to Sunday as “the Lord’s day” are common amongst Brethren.  The biggest clue, though, comes from the links with John Nelson Darby.  [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Nelson_Darby) gives insights into the history of the Brethren and some of their fundamental beliefs.  Below are some partial quotes:

> John Nelson Darby (18 November 1800 – 29 April 1882) was an Anglo-Irish Bible teacher, one of the influential figures among the original Plymouth Brethren and the founder of the Exclusive Brethren. He is considered to be the father of modern Dispensationalism and Futurism. Pre-tribulation rapture theology was popularized extensively in the 1830s by John Nelson Darby and the Plymouth Brethren, and further popularized in the United States in the early 20th century by the wide circulation of the Scofield Reference Bible.

> In 1848, Darby became involved in a complex dispute over the proper method for maintaining shared standards of discipline in different assemblies that resulted in a split between Open Brethren, which maintained a congregational form of government and Exclusive Brethren. After that time, he was recognized as the dominant figure among the Exclusives, who also came to be known as "Darbyite" Brethren.

> Darby is noted in the theological world as the father of "dispensationalism", whose eschatology was adopted and later made popular in the United States by Cyrus Scofield's Scofield Reference Bible.

> Darby has been credited with originating the pre-tribulational rapture theory wherein Christ will suddenly remove His bride, the Church, from this world to its heavenly destiny before the judgments of the tribulation.

Regarding their hymn book, ‘Spiritual Songs’, this was created by John Nelson Darby circa 1856.

There are some independent Brethren denominations that disassociate themselves from the original Plymouth Brethren and the Exclusive Brethren, whilst retaining theological beliefs.  An independent evangelical church exists in the town where I live and a nicer group of Christians would be hard to find.  The women wear a head-covering, and are not allowed to participate vocally in services (other than to sing).  Only the men may pray out loud. Although I’ve never seen a Darby Bible used, or singing from ‘Spiritual Songs’, the founding members of this little church came from a Brethren background.

Comment: Lesley, when you say that women members are denied active vocal participation in services, how can you conclude that a nicer group of Christians would be hard to find ?

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan The basis for that is, largely, from the apostle Paul, 'I suffer not a woman to teach' and _And if they will learn any thing, let them ask their husbands at home: for it is a shame for women to speak in the church._ 1 Corinthians 14:35. This is quite common practice.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Their "niceness" comes from their faith in God and their love for one another, and their active involvement within the community. Same applies to my former neighbours who were active members of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints. As for not allowing women to speak up in a church service, that puts me neither up nor down. It's hardly a matter that determines ones eternal salvation! I also believe that no woman should have authority over a man within the church, and that applies to preaching and teaching. Christian men should take the lead in such matters.

Comment: Still, I live by [the philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiter_Rule) that "a person who is nice to you but rude to the waitstaff is not a nice person".

Comment: You mean hypocrites? Well, I agree that hypocrites are not "nice" people. The LDS family I knew were anything but hypocritical, and genuinely tried to live according to their faith. The fact that I disagreed with their theology does not detract from them being "nice".

Comment: @Lesley - So you're saying I should put in an exception for those who claim "being rude to the waitstaff" is part of their faith? A faith created by human beings and which they freely chose to follow. Well ... no.

Comment: @T.E.D. No, I am not saying that at all because "being nice" in the context of my comment has nothing to do with their religious beliefs.  I've met "nice" Jehovah's Witnesses and "nice" Muslims. I don't know any folks who are "rude to the waitstaff" but if I come across one, you can be sure I will cross them off my Christmas card list!

Answer (score 4):

A "denomination" strictly refers to how groups of churches organise themselves under a single authority structure. So independent churches can be called non-denominational. But independent churches can still be analysed as being part of a *branch* of Christianity.

Lots of what you have described would fit within the [Brethren churches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_Brethren), which are Protestant churches that emphasise the leadership of elders in each local church and often have dispensational theology. Without being a formal denomination, Brethren churches often co-operate for missionary work or theological education.

The main possible difference is that Brethren churches are very firmly lead by elders. Some churches might call their elders pastors, but not all. I couldn't tell from what you said whether your church would consider elders part of the ecclesiology they reject.

If you do have elders then actually what you've written sounds like a quite typical Brethren church, though on the more traditional side, as many Brethren churches now don't expect their women to be completely silent or veiled, and they'll have more varied music than from a single hymn book.

(Note that the existence of a hymn book implies some amount of cooperation with other churches, as publishing a hymn book is beyond the capacity of almost all local churches, aside from huge megachurches. Looking up the publisher of your hymn book might reveal more about the non-denominational connections your church makes.)